# How can I access a spring bean in Activiti JavaDelegate?

Tags: spring, workflow, javabeans, activiti

I'm trying to get a simple Spring example to work with Activiti 5.5, and having some trouble. I'm using the process engine configured with activiti under %activiti_home%/apps/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/activiti-rest.

I modified the spring config file so that it performs an include of my custom spring configuration file:

```
<import resource="classpath*:applicationContext*.xml"/>
```

I deployed my applicationContext.xml file to the activiti-rest/WEB-INF/classes folder. 
Activiti starts up fine, and I see the System.out.println in my bean constructor, so I know that my spring config is being read and the bean is being constructed. I created a spring bean for the class that implements JavaDelegate and injected my bean to it and it always comes up null.

Here is my Spring Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="myBean" class="org.bpmn.examples.MyBean"/>
    <bean id="taskBean" class="org.bpmn.examples.GetBeanTest">
            <property name="myBean" ref="myBean"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my Bean:

```
package org.bpmn.examples;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    public MyBean() {
        super();
        System.out.println("<========================== myBean ===========================>");
        System.out.println("<========================== myBean ===========================>");
        System.out.println("<========================== myBean ===========================>");
    }
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2867207654072787909L;
    Long id;
    String description;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Here is my class that implements the JavaDelegate:

```
package org.bpmn.examples;

import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;

public class GetBeanTest implements JavaDelegate {

    private MyBean myBean;

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        if(myBean == null){
            System.out.println("Bean was null!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Bean is valid!");
        }

    }

    public void setMyBean(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }
}
```

This all seems pretty straightforward to me, however I think the problem is that Activiti is not using a spring bean in the class that is being invoked on my JavaService task, it is creating a new instance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="TestSpringConfig" name="TestSpringConfig">
    <documentation>Place documentation for the 'TestSpringConfig' process here.</documentation>
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="BeanTest" activiti:class="org.bpmn.examples.GetBeanTest"></serviceTask>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" name="" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="servicetask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" name="" sourceRef="servicetask1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

How do I get a reference to a Spring Bean either a simple one such as I have here, or one that has been configured as a JPA Entity?

Any/All replies appreciated!

---

6.28.2011
Updated:
In trying to change the activiti-rest app to use the SpringProcessEngineConfiguration instead of the standalone StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration, I changed the activiti-cfg.xml file in the activiti-cfg.jar file and restarted Tomcat.

I change the xml file to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/activiti" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

  <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration"/>
  <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
  <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
  <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService" />
  <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService" />
  <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService" />

</beans>
```

When I restarted Tomcat no exceptions appear, however when I bring up Explorer and try to login, I get the following Exception:

```
INFO: Server startup in 12011 ms
10:32:02,338  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 05280000 Wrapped Exception (with status template): null
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 05280000 Wrapped Exception (with status template): null
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:742)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:167)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of my project uses Activiti with spring. I think that JavaDelagate can be the problem. You can call from activiti's service task every spring bean this way:

bean definition:

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="org.bpmn.examples.ExampleBean"/>
```

activiti xml:

```
<serviceTask id="servicetask" name="Example" activiti:expression="${exampleBean.doSomething()}"></serviceTask>
```

You can also pass parameters to the functions for example process variables:

```
<serviceTask id="servicetask" name="Example" activiti:expression="${exampleBean.doSomething(processVariable)}"></serviceTask>
```

I always use service tasks this way, and haven't got problem with singleton beans.
Hope it helps. Please take a comment, if I didn't understand your problem.

**UPDATE:**

My project uses activiti like an embedded workflow engine. Activiti uses the same applicationContext with my webapp.

My process engine configuration:

```
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="databaseType" value="mssql" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
        <property name="deploymentResources" value="classpath*:/diagrams/*.bpmn20.xml" />           
    </bean> 


    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: So is your exampleBean above in the above a JavaDelegate? What is done with the interface method execute?

Comment: Also, are you using the activiti-rest process engine and deploying your classes via a Jar file into the app, or are you creating your own process engine?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check my process engine configuration. exampleBean is a simple Spring bean, not implements JavaDelegate. You can call the bean methods from activiti with the expression that I wrote in my example.

Comment: Can you still access your processes/tasks with the out of the box Activiti tools such as Explorer and Probe?

Comment: I'm not using these tools, because I think these applications are not so stable yet and I couldn't integrate probe with mssql database. I use only one Probe feature (restarting failed activiti jobs), that I have implemented manually. I had to update only the retry numbers in one of the activiti tables.

Comment: While this wasn't the exact solution, it was close enough to get me to where I could figure it out. Thanks for the comments and the examples!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 
@Autowired

to bring in my dependencies. Since the JavaDelegate is not instantiated by Spring, I call

```
applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
```

in the constructor of my Delegate's Superclass, which injects all dependencies into the Delegate. You might wonder where to get the applicationContext from, http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/03/accessing-spring-beans-from-legacy-code.html provides you with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My guess ist that activiti will indeed always create a new instance because activiti is not aware of the fact that it should retrieve an instance from the spring container.

If you haven't checked this resource yet:

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#springintegration

maybe it's what you need (i.e. ProcessEngineFactoryBean)

Comment: Yea, I read that section a few times. It seems to me that the spring configuration is for if you want to build your own process engine from the ground up, or if you want to embed it into an existing app. I want to be able to use the tooling that comes with Activiti such as the explorer and probe. I tried changing the activity-rest config to use the SpringProcessEngineConfiguration instead of the StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration and it broke the tool identity management configuration.  The Spring examples distributed with the project leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: I think you really need to make activiti Spring-aware, that means: Activiti must not control the lifecycle of your process Beans but must retrieve the instances from the Spring container. I am sorry to hear, that the examples do not explain everything in detail. What do you mean by 'broke the tool identity management configuration'? Can you post more details?

Comment: What I am trying to do is use the activiti-rest app, and add my own spring beans to it so that I can reuse the tooling (Explorer and Probe). I changed the activiti-cfg.xml file in the rest app to use the SpringProcessEngineConfiguration instead of the StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration, I could not login to Explorer or probe it threw an NPE for identity service. It appears some additional configuration may be needed to tell the processing engine how to authenticate a user?