# How to access Spring Beans in Activiti JavaDelegate tasks

Tags: java, spring, activiti, business-process-management

I am using activiti 5.16.1 to enable workflow in my project.

I have a spring beans which carry out business task such as populating data from database for a given id.

When I try to use these beans in JavaDelegate task, these beans are not populated.

```
@Component
public class ServiceClassDelegateSample implements JavaDelegate {

    @Autowired
    private SampleService sampleService;

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) throws Exception {

        sampleService.doSomeTask();
    }

}
```

However sampleService is always set to null.

Are you aware of how to use spring beans in JavaDelegate task?

There is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474324/how-can-i-access-a-spring-bean-in-activiti-javadelegate) without any proper solution and I hope there is better way in newer version of Activiti.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it is some kind of glitch in Activiti, but you can easily solve it if you replace

```
<serviceTask id="servicetask" name="Service Task" activiti:class="some.class.path.ServiceClassDelegateSample"></serviceTask>
```

with delegate expression;

```
<serviceTask id="serviceTask" activiti:delegateExpression="${serviceClassDelegateSample}"></serviceTask>
```

where `serviceClassDelegateSample` is a name of your bean.

But why doesn't work in first way, I don't know.

Comment: You are spot on Petar! I was using activiti:class="". I used activiti:delegateExpression=${springBeanWhichImplementsJavaDelegate}

Comment: Quick note - this can be changed within the process definition xml (or through the activiti editor ui)